# Eulerian Graph characterization

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a connected graph $G$ is Eulerian if and only if every edge of $G$ lies on a odd number of cycles.

I try to do it using that every Eulerian graph has every vertex of even degree, and I try to make some cycles but I can't count them.

Comment: http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%203.PDF